# How can I save a some camera frame in vector<Mat> and then play in JavaCameraView?

Tags: java, android, opencv, record, javacameraview

I am using a Android Studio, OpenCV and JavaCameraView to display frame from camera. I want create a simple Mat frame recorder. For example I want save a 100 last frames and then I want a display it in JavaCameraView.

I have vector recordedCameraFrames for store a Mat frames. In function onCameraFrame I have ...

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame cameraFrame) {

colorMat = cameraFrame.rgba();

if(frameCountForRecording < 100){
    recordedCameraFrames.add(colorMat);
    frameCountForRecording++;
}       
else {
    isRecordedFramesReadyToPlay = true;
    recordedCameraFrames.remove(0);
    recordedCameraFrames.add(colorMat);
}
```

And then when I activate PLAY_DETECTED_FRAMES_VIEW_MODE I want play recorded frames ...

```
case PLAY_DETECTED_FRAMES_VIEW_MODE:

if(isRecordedFramesReadyToPlay == true && canPlayRecordedFrames == true) {
        if (indexOfRecordedFrame == 99) {
              indexOfRecordedFrame = 0;
        }
        indexOfRecordedFrame++;
        colorMat = recordedCameraFrames.get(indexOfRecordedFrame).clone();
}
break;
```

Comment: so.. what's the problem ?

Comment: Problem is that, function onCameraFrame still return original colorMat, no colorMat from vector recordedCameraFrames.

Comment: Where did you return the `colorMat`  from the function?

Comment: In the end of function onCameraFrame I return colorMat.

Comment: You do the same thing in every call `colorMat = cameraFrame.rgba();` in `onCameraFrame()` function. And also you overtide the colorMat in both functions?